# Is it possible to re-import an stl over an existing object when I update the stl?

Tags: objects, import, stl

I am learning to use blender and OpenSCAD to make a textured model and render it. I have set created a simple transformer model in OpenSCAD and wrote this script to export the individual components into separate `.stl` files:

```
$openscadExecutable = "C:\Program Files\OpenSCAD\openscad.exe"

Get-ChildItem ".\openscad" -Filter *.scad |
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    & $openscadExecutable -o "blender\stl\\\$($_.BaseName).stl" $_.FullName
}
```

After that, I went to blender and imported all the stl files into it. Then I spent some time playing around trying texture the model, eventually getting this result:

[image]

It's rendered as orthographic deliberately, I wanted to use it for a 2D game that uses top-down view.

Now an issue is if I want to change anything in the parts of the model, I will probably have to re-import the parts and apply all the settings I have created again. That's a little annoying.

Is it possible to import a model to replace a model of an existing object? For example, if I want to make the coil thicker, could I just select it and pick a new 3D model for that object?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for, but any object is like a "container" for object data ...

[image]

... so you can import your edited model and under Properties Editor > Data Properties you can switch to newly imported data ... so all the transformations done on object level (Loc/Rot/Scale) will be kept.

[image]

... but since material is assigned to a specific group of vertices your previously material would not be assigned to newly imported data block.